# GA send event not firing?

Tags: google-analytics

Trying to set up an analytics event to be fired by Javascript

```
  ga('send', 'event', 'Form', 'Pop Up', 'page load', 'Home Page', {nonInteraction:true});
```

Never get anything in Google Analytics for it - Using tag manager to add analytics to the page but not sure if I missed a step setting stuff up.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Tag Manager you have to insert an event Analytics Tag with a trigger that activates it, in your case I would say it is a Window Loaded trigger (https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679319?hl=en).

Comment: donst seem to do it - but i do think  that is the issue is some way - still investigating